# Spin a processor for a fixed amount of CPU time

Tags: java, concurrency, cpu-usage

I am looking for a way to spin the CPU for a fixed amount of CPU time to simulate fake "work", so that I can test out some concurrent algorithms. Basically, I'm looking for a way to make a thread do something that would take N seconds of CPU time.

My initial implementation had something like:

```
public void doWork() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < mDurationMillis) {
        //Churn
    }
    System.out.println("Task " + mTaskId + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": done work!");
}
```

But I soon realised that this is just measuring real time, and that 100 such tasks would finish in roughly the same time as one on a single processor. Is there a way to measure the CPU time that a thread has used, while it is running?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use *real* work that's typical of the type and amount the algorithms will see in real use. You're quite likely to get meaningless test results if you test with work that's not like the work you plan to do in actual use. On modern CPUs, the concurrency behavior of I/O-heavy (or system call heavy) code is going to be very different from memory-access-heavy code which will be different from code that does lots of floating point math, and so on.

Comment: I recommend running lots (say 100) of competing threads and have them `Thread.sleep(randomMilliseconds)` to simulate variations in timing. If there's a concurrency problem, this approach with the right tests will help find it.

Comment: I have troubles with understanding the question. If a task is executed by a single thread, and all time measurements are done within the task, why would CPU time be (significantly) different from real (aka wall-clock) time? And why do you think that 100 such tasks would finish in roughly the same time as one, on a single processor?

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov: It's not a single thread, it's a single CPU. I have multiple threads, but of course they can't run truly simultaneously. So with my above doWork() function. So if you start five doWork() threads with 1000 duration, they'll all finish roughly a second after the program start. If instead doWork() took say a second to perform some complex computation, the five threads would take five seconds to finish. Same problem with sleep, sleep time is wall clock time not thread CPU time. So sleeps can all execute more or less concurrently on a single CPU.

Comment: I see; forgot about oversubscription and long-running tasks :) Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

With little googling I found [ThreadMXBean interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) which seems to have what you need, as well as [a usage example](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/5303-how-determine-cpu-usage-using-java.html#post11862). However I am not a Java developer, so please take it with a good grain of salt.